# How to play youtube video in polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How to play youtube video in polymer

I want to play a youtube video inside polymer web page. But it plays only audio can't see video or any other controllers to stop video. Even when i point to another page, the video plays in background. I want to show the video and stop the video while pointing to another link page.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-youtube/google-youtube.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-video">
    <template>
      <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      </style>

<paper-dialog class="video-dialog fit">
   <div class="layout horizontal">
    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>
      <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-button>
  </div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
      <google-youtube style="height: 100%;"
        video-id="YMWd7QnXY8E"
        rel="1"
        start="5"
        playsinline="0"
        controls="2"
        showinfo="0"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        autoplay="1">
      </google-youtube></div>
  </paper-dialog>

   </template> 

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-video',
        properties: {

        },

      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the `style` attribute of the `div` surrounding `google-youtube`

Comment: Then also no display only sound is audible

Comment: What did you try to do in order to debug? For example this element (but with the minimal JS also to actually define it) does show the video for me, but the `paper-dialog` element has `display: none`.. so **maybe** that's where you should be looking..

Comment: is there any bower components i am missing. Actually i made display:none and seen it was not working